# Heroku using production configuration instead of staging configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production, staging, environments

I'm running two apps on Heroku, one being myapp-production and the other one being myapp-staging.

For some reason however, the staging app uses the production environment configuration rather than the staging configuration, which I have defined in staging.rb.

The way I set up the staging app was by running

```
heroku create --stack cedar --remote staging
```

and afterwards

```
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --app myapp-staging
```

Yet myapp-staging is still using the production configuration. Any ideas why and how to address that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to add RAILS_ENV=staging too

```
heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=staging --app myapp-staging
```

Comment: sadly, Heroku's https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration (as of today 2/21/2013) doesn't mention RAILS_ENV at all. I figured it out like you did, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your dynos (`heroku restart`) after making this change to your configuration?

Comment: adding config variables automatically restarts the application.

Comment: Ack! Of course. I was just about to add the same message as @JohnBeynon - just tested that on an app and can confirm that it works as expected.